# What can extreme tinitis and other ear problems be related to?

Tags: hearing, ear, tinnitus, ears-nose-throat-ent, middle-ear

I am desperate for some kind of help with this.

I have a very frustrating inner ear condition which has changed over a few years, becoming seemingly more serious. Having heard many possible causes from a professional, I now want to see for myself if any of them hold any merit. Thus, I am now looking to find any avenues of research into fluid build-up, eustachian tube or sinus dysfunction relating to any other condition.

Just to clarify, I'm not here for a diagnosis, I'm asking if anybody knows of any research material describing a link between otic conditions such as OME and any other cranial etc, medical condition.

Comment: You need an evaluation by a second ENT. Unfortunately, we can't help you because site rules prohibit providing personal medical advice.

Comment: I appreciate the reply and I have informed my doctor that I want to see a _different_ ENT specialist, so yet again, I am on the waiting list. I'm not looking for personal medical advice per se, but rather information on any known links between OME (or similar) and any cranium condition or any condition that is located in the head. We can separate that from my problem if it helps. I'm just looking for research material. Thanks.

Comment: I read that tinnitus is caused by overactive neurons in the region related to hearing (when it's not a physical injury or related to hearing loss). So if you take caffeine or chocolate, it will stimulate the brain and increase tinnitus. Sorry I don't have a solution. You can follow up with that research. My guess is some type of electro-magnetic cranial stimulation might have an effect on it. Maybe depressants will also have an effect? I prefer mild stimulants.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can piece together, you are asking about the relationship between *fluid build-up, eustachian tube or sinus dysfunction* and *other cranial* conditions. The key thing to realize is that the [eustachian tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustachian_tube) connects the nasopharynx to the middle ear. Fluid build up is almost always a middle ear issue. Inner ear diseases are things like [Meniere's disease](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/menieres-disease/basics/definition/con-20028251).

The [middle ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_ear) is an isolated space located in bones of the skull and not in the *brain*. In extreme cases middle ear infections can infect the bones separating the middle ear and inner ear and can lead to meningitis and brain abscesses: http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Otitis-media/Pages/Complications.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant the middle-ear. The symptoms of Meniere's disease fits my profile to a tee though. Although the symptoms do seem to be very similar to a middle-ear infection, or aggravation caused by the sinuses.(?) None of the other complications seem like a good avenue, but thanks it all has value to me.